# Closing the popups instead of going back to the last page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

In many popups I had this Line to close the popup:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
```

The problem was that this didn't close the popup but going back one page which is not what I wanted to do because it would go one before the page that contained the popup so I did this instead:

```
<a data-role="button" data-inline="true" onclick="$(this).closest('[data-role=popup]').popup('close');">Cancel</a>
```

But it's still doing the same thing as before. I'm confused, could someone please help me to discover my error?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused, why not just use a "onclick='$('#IdOfPopup').hide();'" type of solution?

Comment: well, because I'm using this in many popups so I don't have to do it for each popup and I can just do a search and replace on all of them

Comment: In that case my comment would still apply, but instead of doing this based on an ID, do this based on a class, and give all popups the same class. I'm assuming you don't have multiple popups open at once here.